# Common gradle cache between multiple OS (Windows and a Linux flavour dual boot)?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

How can I keep (or can I keep) gradle cache the same over different operating systems?
i.e. point gradle to cache in a common directory and share that directory to the other OS
Operating systems can be different (i.e. Windows, Ubuntu, ,Arch, maybe Mac)

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what exactly you want to know? How to make gradle keep it's cache in some custom directory? Or how to share that common directory between different operating systems? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable, gradle.user.home system property, or --gradle-user-home command line parameter.

Source: [How to change Gradle download location](http://You%20can%20set%20the%20GRADLE_USER_HOME%20environment%20variable,%20gradle.user.home%20system%20property,%20or%20--gradle-user-home%20command%20line%20parameter.)